# Having problem with finding the number of ordered pairs.

Tags: combinatorics, functions, relations

[image]

Y and Z are proper subset of X this means that X is having all the elements of Y and Z and also Y$\ne$X and Z$\ne$X (This is because we are talking about proper subset and not just subset).

Let Y={1} and Z={2,3,4,5} here the number of ordered pair is 4

Now let Y={2} and Z={1,3,4,5} here the number of ordered pair is 4

Now let Y={3} and Z={1,2,4,5} here the number of ordered pair is 4

Now let Y={4} and Z={1,2,3,5} here the number of ordered pair is 4

Now let Y={5} and Z={1,2,3,4} here the number of ordered pair is 4

I can only see these four possibility of Y and Z and according to me the total number of ordered pair is 4*5=20.

What I think is that if you take Y other than above say Y={2,3} then the ordered pair here which you get is already obtained in the above cases.

**Answer in book is $3^5$** There is no explanation given in book.

Comment: Y and Z are not proper subsets of X according to the picture

Comment: Read the question!! $(\{1\},\{2,3,4,5\})$ is one of the ordered pairs you are asked to count, $\{2,3\},\{1,4,5\})$ is another, $(1,3)$ is ***not*** one of the ordered pairs you are asked to count, because $1$ and $3$ are ***not*** subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement that $Y \cap Z = \emptyset$ does not imply that $Y \cup Z = X$.  For instance, $Y = \{1\}$ and $Z = \{2, 3\}$ are disjoint, but $Y \cup Z \neq X$.  Also, note that the question does not require that $Y$ and $Z$ be proper subsets.

If the subsets $Y$ and $Z$ of $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ are disjoint, each of the five element of $X$ is either in $Y$, in $Z$, or neither.  Hence, there are $3^5$ ordered pairs of subsets $(Y, Z)$ such that $Y \subseteq X$, $Z \subseteq X$, and $X \cap Y = \emptyset$.

Comment: @Taussig Sir please can you elaborate your answer. And what is wrong with the reasons which I have given?

Comment: @Singh Revised.  Did I address your question?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Did you read the OP's question, where he showed that he completely misunderstands the problem statement?

Comment: Evidently, the OP thinks he is supposed to count the elements of $$\bigcup\{Y\times Z:Y\subseteq X,\ Z\subseteq X,\ Y\cap Z=\emptyset\}.$$

Comment: @Taussig Sir If I take Y={1} and Z={2,3,4,5} then there will be four ordered pair (Y,Z). There are five elements in X. In X x X (X cross X) there will be 25 elements out of this there will be (1,1),(2,2),...,(5,5) which will not be included in case of (Y,Z). So I think answer should be 20.

Comment: It seems to me that you are counting ordered pairs of single elements $(a, b)$ in which $a \neq b$.  However, we want to count ordered pairs of disjoint subsets of $X$.  $(\{1\}, \{2, 3, 4, 5\})$ is one such ordered pair.  $(\{1\}, \{2, 3\})$ is another.   Ordered pairs of disjoint subsets are determined by deciding whether each element of $X$ is in $Y$, in $Z$, or neither.

Comment: @Taussing Sir thank you very much. After reading the question for the first time I thought that it is talking about the ordered pair (Y,Z) where first term belongs to the set Y and second belong to Z. Its my mistake that (Y,Z) is not same as (y,z). From now onwards I will remember that sets problems are "case sensitive"!! Once again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can pick the set $Y$ of $k$ elements in $5 \choose k$ ways (any subset of $X$ with k elements).
For each such pick/choice of Y, you can then pick $Z$ in $2^{5-k}$ ways
(as a sub-set of the remaining $5-k$ elements from $X$).

So the total number of ways to form the couple $(Y,Z)$ is:

$\sum_{k=0}^5 {5 \choose k } \cdot 2^{5-k}$

This can be rewritten as:

$\sum_{k=0}^5 {5 \choose k } \cdot 1^k \cdot 2^{5-k}$

As we know from the binomial formula this is equal to $3^5$.